# How I can show short content with short tag

Tags: functions, the-content

I am using Wordpress and I want to show ** short content with limit ** of words for every post on home page and for this I am using this code

functions.php

```
function abc_the_content($num_words) {

$get_the_content = get_the_content();
$striptag_from_content = strip_tags($get_the_content);
echo $content = wp_trim_words($striptag_from_content, $num_words = $num_words, $more = null)}
```

home.php

```
 abc_get_content(100);
```

It's showing content perfectly but when i use  `[gallery]` short-code inside post editor, it only shows me the text rather than the gallery. this also causes issues when i am using `vemio vedio` tags because it strips my tags.

I just want to strip image tag from editor not any other tag like `vemio` or gallery short code.
How i can modify my `function.php` ?

Comment: Your function is too limited for what you want it to do. A better suggestion is to re-use an existing function for the job, there is one in core to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

```
function abc_the_content($num_words) {
    global $post;
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $content = strip_tags($content);
    $content = wp_trim_words($content, $num_words, $more = null);
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);
}
```

change the strip tags line to this one if you want to strip out only the img tag

```
    $content = preg_replace("/<\/?img(.|\s)*?>/i", '', $content);
```